# awk on a date variable

Tags: date, sorting, awk

What is working :

```
echo "Oct 12 2021" | awk '{print "date -d\""$1FS$2FS$3"\" +%Y%m%d"}' | bash
```

how could I use a variable on a bash script ?

```
mydate="Oct 12 2021"
awk -v dateformat= ''$mydate" '{print "date -d\""$1FS$2FS$3"\" +%Y%m%d"}'
```

Comment: Please give a little more information about your intention. Do you wish to use awk to format a date held in the variable mydate? Or store the result from awk in a variable? What is your intent in writing dateformat= ?

Comment: store the result of awk in a variable but replace echo "date" by a variable. Use both variable in fact ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously wouldn't really use `awk` to call `date` on a single value but I assume you have something more than that in mind in your real code so this is what you asked for (call GNU `date` from awk using an awk variable as the date):

```
mydate="Oct 12 2021"
awk -v date="$mydate" 'BEGIN {
   system("date -d\047" date "\047 +\047%Y%m%d\047")
}'
20211012
```

or if you prefer:

```
awk -v date="$mydate" 'BEGIN {
    cmd = "date -d\047" date "\047 +\047%Y%m%d\047"
    print ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : date"=N/A" )
    close(cmd)
}'
20211012
```

Don't do either of those though. It's very slow to call an external command from awk and you don't need to when all you want to do is change text from one format to another:

```
$ awk -v date="$mydate" 'BEGIN {
    split(date,d);
    mth = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[1])+2)/3
    printf "%04d%02d%02d\n", d[3], mth, d[2]
}'
20211012
```

Also, if you have GNU awk it has built-in time functions so even if what you wanted to do wasn't just shuffling bits of text around you could call the internal `mktime()` and `strftime()` instead of the external `date`:

```
awk -v date="$mydate" 'BEGIN {
    split(date,d)
    mth = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[1])+2)/3
    secs = mktime(d[3]" "mth" "d[2]" 12 0 0")
    print strftime("%Y%m%d",secs)
}'
20211012
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original example uses awk to prepare arguments that are then passed to the Linux date command running in bash; the date formatting is performed by the date command.

You don't need awk for this, the date command -d option is very flexible in the format it receives.

```
mydate="Oct 3 2021"
date -d "$mydate" +%Y%m%d
```

Will give you a formatted date. You can assign the result to a variable using the $() syntax - run a command and assign result

```
formattedDate=$(date -d "$mydate" +%Y%m%d)
echo $formattedDate
```